# How can I get the format of a parsed string

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, format

DateTime.Parse takes a string and returned the equivalent DateTime.

Is there a way to get the format being used by the parser?

For example, 7/19/2011 would return M/dd/yyyy while 19-7-2011 would return dd-M-yyyy.

DateTime.TryParseExact would work for me if it also returned the format being used.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible because the mapping between a `DateTime` format and a particular output is not isomorphic (there is no inverse mapping to a single format for each output) - consider just the case 11-07-2011 - is this dd-MM-yyyy or MM-dd-yyyy?

Comment: Correct. But you could say that there is no isomorphism between strings and DateTimes. Yet, the parsing string -> DateTime works fine.

Comment: @user380719: Yes, because any ambiguity is resolved for you by the framework using sensible defaults/using higher priority on certain formats - without that this would not work, and you 'd be left with `DateTime.ParseExact()` where you **must** specify the format.

Comment: Indeed, ParseExact is almost what I am looking for. If I could pass an array of formats and it would tell me which one it uses, I'd be happy.

Answer (score 1):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx  Specifically the Remarks section.

The best way to get the formats that it looks for is to read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

**`DateTime.Parse`** uses the current culture of the current thread.
**`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat`** will give you a readonly instance of **`DateTimeFormatInfo`** that you can use to inspect the format.

The property **`ShortDatePattern`** is the one you are looking for.
This addresses your question regarding the format being used by the parser but there is no way to get the format after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through a list of formats that you pass one at a time to DateTime.TryParseExact.

When you finally get a true value then you know exactly which format .Net would use to parse it.